# React Joyride-How can I adjust position of floater?

Tags: reactjs

I want to adjust the position of the floater for a particular step, I was trying to do:

```
floaterProps: {
  styles: {
    tooltip: {
      top: -200
    },
  arrow: { 
    top:-200
  }
}
```

But it is not working!
Is this the wrong way?

Comment: did you try using `setState`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position: absolute` in your tooltip and then adjust the position with `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` properties. more about positioning on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) documentation.

```
tooltip: {
  position: absolute,
  top: 20px,
  left: 10px,
}
```

If you are trying to use multi-tooltips in your application, you can also adjust their position in the `Z` axis by adding `z-index` property. more information on  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) documentation.